# How to use JSON on POST in Python Requests

Tags: python, json, http-post

How I can use this JSON Data on POST

```
{"data":"{\"email\":\"anything65@gmail.com\",\"agreedToTerms\":true,\"profile\":{\"profileTypeID\":1,\"agreedToTerms\":true,\"firstName\":\"name\",\"lastName\":\"dfghjefws\",\"errors\":{}}}"}
```

This is My currently code, I got every time "message: Server Error"

```
data_profile2 = {"data":"{\"email\":\"anything65@gmail.com\",\"agreedToTerms\":true,\"profile\":{\"profileTypeID\":2,\"agreedToTerms\":true,\"firstName\":\"name\",\"lastName\":\"dfgh jefws\",\"errors\":{}}}"}
reqeust_1 = session.post(url_profile,headers=headers_profile, json=data_profile2)
```

Comment: What is the purpose of using \ before " in JSON data ?

Comment: Your code might be perfectly acceptable for some websites, server error indicates its an issue with the website receiving the data.

Comment: Why is your json contains a json dump in it? is this what the server expect? other wise just send it as a regular dict ( {"data":{"email":"..."}} )

Comment: I am a beginner in python, I really copied the json data from website (debugging network) but I can't use it in POST it give me "Server Error" in the response

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to use dict on this json data please

Comment: @RFOoDxMoDz that´s a python dict `data_profile2={"data": {"email": "anything65@gmail.com", "agreedToTerms": True , "profile": {"profileTypeID": 1,"agreedToTerms": True, "firstName": "name", "lastName": "dfghjefws", "errors": {}}}}`

Comment: now I used dict on JSON and I got same result

`params = dict ( {"data":{"email":"anything65@gmail.com",'agreedToTerms':True,'profile':{'profileTypeID':1,'agreedToTerms':True,'firstName':"dfgkhjefws",'lastName':"dfglhjefws",'errors':{}}}} )
reqeust_profile = session.post(url_profile,headers=headers_profile, json=params)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[requests doc](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)

[POST request](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#make-a-request)

```py
import requests

payload= {"data": {"email": "anything65@gmail.com", "agreedToTerms": True , "profile": {"profileTypeID": 1,"agreedToTerms": True, "firstName": "name", "lastName": "dfghjefws", "errors": {}}}}
request_1 = requests.get(url_profile, headers=headers_profile, data=payload)
```

#### update

If you use `json=payload`, your `Content-Type` in header will be `application/json` automatically.
I assume that a `session` is not mandatory for that you want to do. `Sessions` persist parameters across many requests.